# Different ways to initialize a variable

Tags: bash, variables, syntax

As far as I've seen there are two ways to initialize a variable with the output of a process. Is there any difference between these two?

```
ex1=`echo 'hello world'`
ex2=$(echo 'hello world')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get same effect.

The `$()` is recommended since it's more readable and makes it easier to nest one `$()` into another `$()`.

**Update:**

The `$()` syntax is a POSIX 1003.1 standard (2004 edition). However, on some older UNIX systems (SunOS, HP-UX, etc.) the `/bin/sh` does not understand it.

You might need to use backtick "`" instead or use another shell (usually it's ksh) if you need your script to work on such environment.

If you don't know which syntax to use - use `$()`. Backtick syntax is deprecated.

Comment: @samus: $() is indeed POSIX (1003.2 I think), but it will not work on old UNIXes. Trust me - I use them everyday.

Comment: but that's the point, when we talk about portability we mean POSIX because it's the current standard supported by most platforms, if you have specific requirements that go beyond this then it's a particular case.

Comment: @samus: By "more portable" I mean "works on more OSes" not "is compatible with newer POSIX standard".

Answer (score 4):

see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

also notice that `$()` is POSIX so it does work on sh.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to initialize a variable to a default one if you haven't initialized it yourself.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] a="I have initialized var a"
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo ${a:="Default value"}
I have initialized var a
[jaypal:~/Temp] a=
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo ${a:="Default value"}
Default value
```

Comment: So that operator reads the new value of the variable and outputs the old value. :)

Comment: It is generally used when you pass on values to your script as `$1`, `$2` and helps your script run even when those values are not explicitly passed. By this you can implicitly set your variables to run on default values if a value hasn't been assigned to them. This saves about 4-5 lines of code where you check if the variable has been assigned or not, something like `if [ -z "$var" ] then; …`

Comment: I believe, we can either use,
echo ${a:="Default value"}
or
echo ${a:-"Default value"}